# python 3.3: struct.pack won't accept strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use struct.pack to write a padded string to a file but it seems with the 3.x interpreters this doesn't work anymore. An example of how I'm using it:

```
mystring = anotherString+" sometext here"
output = struct.pack("30s", mystring);
```

This seems to be okay in earlier versions of python but with 3 it produces an error demanding a byte object. The docs seem to imply that it supposed to do a conversion of any string to a UTF-8 byte object without complaint (and I don't care if a multi-byte character happens to be truncated):

http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/struct.html:
*"The c, s and p conversion codes operate on bytes objects, but packing with such codes also supports str objects, which are encoded using UTF-8."*

Am I misreading the docs and how are others using struct.pack with strings?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, up until 3.1 `struct.pack()` erroneously would implicitly encode strings to UTF-8 bytes; this was fixed in Python 3.2. See [issue 10783](http://bugs.python.org/issue10783).

The conclusion was that the implicit conversion was a Bad Idea, and it was reverted while the developers still had a chance to do so:

> I prefer to break the API today than having to maintain a broken API for
>   10 or 20 years :-)  And we have a very small user base using Python 3,
>   it's easier to change it now, than in the next release.

This is also documented in the [porting section of the 3.2 What's New guide](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html#porting-to-python-3-2):

> `struct.pack()` now only allows bytes for the `s` string pack code. Formerly, it would accept text arguments and implicitly encode them to bytes using UTF-8. This was problematic because it made assumptions about the correct encoding and because a variable-length encoding can fail when writing to fixed length segment of a structure.

You need to explicitly encode your strings before packing.

Answer (score 3):

I could be wrong but in this case won't `.encode('UTF-8')` work? 
eg:

```
output = struct.pack("30s", mystring.encode('UTF-8'));
```

I stand to be corrected.

Comment: Sure this'll work, but that wasn't the question. The issue was that the documentation implied a string object would be fine, and for a while that actually worked too.